# How convert int to enum value c++

Tags: c++, enums

How can I do it

```
int k = 23;
enum stat_t {
    first = 0,
    second,
    last = k 
};
```

May be you know how can I do it?

Comment: Make that `const int k = 23;`.

Comment: This does not make a lot of sense. Enum's are declarations and need to be known at compile time. The int k here is a non-const variable. If it would have been const/constexpr, then you could just as well write last = 23

Comment: @StarShine: Unless that named constant (`k`) appears in several places.

Comment: So why not use the enum instead then?

Comment: @StarShine: To convey the author's intention, for example. The reason for using named constants in the first place. Not that `k` is particularly descriptive, but then the OP's code merely illustrates the issue.

Comment: Yes, I guess dogmatic approaches are never really sensible. It wouldn't make a lot of sense to use enum's for integer constants only and (obviously) not for any other type of constants. Even if this is perfectly valid and quite common practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `const`.

```
int const k = 23;
enum stat_t {
    first = 0,
    second,
    last = k 
};
```

Comment: Its work! Thanks!

It was example, I try it
I need do this 
int k = vector.size();

enum stat_t {
    first = 0,
    second,
    last = k 
};